# Object with fields (one-to-many relations) becomes without fields with Entity Framework

Tags: sql, entity-framework, sqlite, orm, one-to-many

I use Entity Framework and SQLite.

The context:

```
public class WordContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<VmWord> Words { get; set; }
    public DbSet<LearnDay> LearnDay { get; set; }

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        optionsBuilder.UseSqlite("Data Source=db_name.db");
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }
}
```

The models:

```
public class Word
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public IList<LearnDay> LearnDay { get; set; }
}

public class LearnDay
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Key { get; set; }
    public int Value { get; set; }
    public Word Word { get; set; }
}
```

How I initialize and save object:

```
using (var db = new WordContext())
{
    db.Words.Add(new VmWord
    {
        LearnDay = new List<LearnDay> 
                    {
                        new LearnDay {
                            Key = "pl",
                            Value = 0
                        },
                        new LearnDay {
                            Key = "en",
                            Value = 0
                        }
                    }
    });
    db.SaveChanges();
}
```

At this steep it looks like it work ok, I open the db and check that tables contain this data.

But then I try to get object and it returns with:

> LearnDay == null

```
using (var db = new WordContext())
{
    // word != null but LearnDay == null
    var word = db.Words.Where(p => p.Id == testId).FirstOrDefault();
}
```

And if I do:

```
using (var db = new WordContext())
{
    // learnDay != null
    // learnDay.Word !=null
    // even learnDay.Word.learnDay !=null
    var learnDay = db.LearnDay.Where(p => p.Word == testWord).FirstOrDefault();

    // then try again to get word:
    // word != null
    // LearnDay != null
    var word = db.Words.Where(p => p.Id == testId).FirstOrDefault();
}
```

And after last steep I get the object with fields != null. How do I solve it?

Answer (score 0):

I should to use Include() method:

```
var word = db.Words.Include(x => x.LearnDay).Where(p => p.Id == testId).FirstOrDefault();
```